# tomcat webapp not authenticating to sendmail on migrated server

Tags: tomcat, sendmail

## Issue Overview

I'm in the process of a P2V migration and I've run into a snag getting tomcat and sendmail to play nice. I can't get the application to send mail out.

The major differences between the two systems are:

- The OS is being upgraded from CentOS 5.6 to CentOS 7.2
- Sendmail is upgraded from 8.13.8 to 8.14.7
- Tomcat used to be run as root and is now run as tomcat

The same setup (minus the differences above) is currently working in the physical environment.

The application connects without specifying a user or password. There's nothing in the sendmail configs that set up authentication other than this in sendmail.mc:

```
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
```

### Logs

They key error I get from catalina.out is:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:590)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at com.tw.manage.business.services.MailService.sendMessage(MailService.java:97)
```

[Full error here on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/KAKpUSBK)

[Decompiled com.tw.manage.business.services.MailService.sendMessage code here.](http://pastebin.com/cVuvUfhQ)

Relevant app.properties here:

```
# Mail properties
# ---------------

# email server host
mailer.smtp.host=localhost

# email server port
mailer.smtp.port=25

# protocol either smtp or smtps
mailer.protocol=smtp

# user account
mailer.user=

# user password
mailer.password=

# either text/plain or text/html
mailer.mime.type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
mailer.subject.mime.type=UTF-8

# email message from email address
mailer.from=donotreply@company.com
```

Here's the error in /var/log/maillog:

```
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: assigned id
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: NOQUEUE: connect from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: AUTH: available mech=GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI ANONYMOUS, allowed mech=EXTERNAL GSSAPI KERBEROS_V4 DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: Milter: no active filter
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 220 app-server.company.inc ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.14.7; Wed, 18 Jan 2017 14:02:40 -0500
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: <-- EHLO app-server
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-app-server.company.inc Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-PIPELINING
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-8BITMIME
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-SIZE
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-DSN
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-ETRN
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-AUTH GSSAPI
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250-DELIVERBY
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 250 HELP
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: disconnect level 1
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: in background, pid=46298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: --- 421 4.4.1 app-server.company.inc Lost input channel from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: lost input channel from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] to MTA after ehlo
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: disconnect level 1
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: in background, pid=46298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x4001, OpMode=d, pid=46298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: unlink ./dfv0IJ2exL046298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: ./dfv0IJ2exL046298: unlink-fail 2
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: unlink ./qfv0IJ2exL046298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: ./qfv0IJ2exL046298: unlink-fail 2
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: unlock
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: unlink ./xfv0IJ2exL046298
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: v0IJ2exL046298: ./xfv0IJ2exL046298: unlink-fail 2
Jan 18 14:02:40 app-server sendmail[46298]: NOQUEUE: finis, pid=46298
```

### Things I've tried

All configurations in /etc/mail are the same, bit for bit. I've verified that there are no environmental changes necessary, such as hostnames - the configs only ever call localhost or localhost.localdomain.

I've put the following in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost old-app-hostname.vendor.net app-server app-server.company.inc
```

I've tested sending mail as root and other local accounts by using `telnet localhost 25` and was able to receive mail in my gmail from the server using the desired from e-mail address.

I've also attempted running tomcat as root.

Comment: It seems that your sendmail sendmail supports only GSSAPI authentication. Take a look at http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/auth.html for info how to debug/fix authentication in sendmail.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip - If you're referring to this line in maillog: --- 250-AUTH GSSAPI

The same line appears when I successfully send via telnet or from the command line using mail. There's no auth options configured in sendmail.mc, in addition my access file should allow unauthenticated access from the localhost:
`Connect:127.0.0.1   RELAY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that default options must have changed. In sendmail 8.13 LOGIN was being offered by default. In 8.14 it appears GSSAPI is now being offered by default. The following line in /etc/mail/sendmail.mc allowed the blank login from tomcat, after restarting sendmail:

```
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `LOGIN')dnl
```